# How can I get a collection with all payment methods?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, collection, payment-methods

I need to get a collection of all payment methods and list the quantity of orders on each of them, how can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the array to collection in the following way:

```
$allActivePaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
foreach($allActivePaymentMethods as $row){
   $data=array('id'=>$row->getId(),'store'=>$row->getStore());
   $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
   $rowObj->setData($data);
   $collection->addItem($rowObj);
}

//now you can get the data using collection way
foreach($collection as $_data){
  print_r($_data->getData());
}
```

Comment: It kinda of worked, but it's making a collection with null values, however, when I print_r the array(not the collection) it's returning an array with these values:
Array ( [id] => free [store] => ) Array ( [id] => cashondelivery [store] => ) Array ( [id] => paypal_billing_agreement [store] => )
I need to make my collection show those values, and also need to show the quantity of orders made with the payment method in question.

Comment: Actually  there is object in each array, So you need to build the data array before converting to an object. I have modified the answer, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

These are class methods `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Config.php`

To get a list with all payments active and inactive:

```
$allAvailablePaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();
```

To get a list with all active payment methods:

```
$allActivePaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
```

To get a list with all credit cards that Magento supports:

```
$allCcTypes = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getCcTypes();
```

Comment: I tried this solution a while ago and can't use that because I need a collection, not an array, also tried to convert those arrays to a collection object but for no avail.

Comment: Do you know how to efficiently convert those arrays on a collection, so I can display on a grid?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to implement it.